# How to send date value to elasticsearch aggregation query in C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am running an aggregation query and it works fine. I need to update the specific date range as "Last 12 Months" using the following code.
But the date range is not applying here.
How to resolve this?
Thanks

``

```
       DateTime d = new DateTime();

        d = DateTime.Now;
        //var startDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1);
        //var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(-12);

        var searchResponse = client.Count<Location>(
            s => s
            .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
            .Must(f2 => f2.DateRange(date => date
            .Field("@jobdate")
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(d.AddDays(-365))
            .LessThanOrEquals(d.AddDays(-1))
            )
            )
            )
            ).Query(c => c
            .QueryString(d => d
           .Query("city: \"Chicago\"")
             )
            )
            );
```

``

Comment: could you share your index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Use Date Histogram Aggregation in NEST:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-histogram-aggregation-usage.html